# Disassemble IL code into C# with line numbers using MDB (or mdb2pdb?)

Tags: c#, mono, ilspy, dotpeek

Does anyone know of tools that can disassemble IL back into C# code and use information stored in a mdb file to annotate the line numbers of the dissassembled IL?

I am trying to investigate stack traces that have line numbers included without having the exact source code that was used to compile. But I got an mdb file.

At the moment, I am using **dotPeek** and **ILSpy** to do the disassembling for me, but I don't seem to find any option to specify an mdb.

There is a non-editable section "**Pdb**" under the properties of DLL in **dotPeek** **1.4**, but I couldn't find a **mdb2pdb** converter either. (only **pdb2mdb** included in Mono).

Comment: why does it matter? If you don'T have original source codes, why would you want to preserve symbols in original mdb. you can generate a new pdb and decompiled sources with dotpeek

Comment: I am analyzing stack traces to find bugs in 3rd party libraries. I can't easily recompile the project that I am trying to find the error for.

Comment: Then again... maybe I could decompile the whole DLL, recompile it, replace and start debugging.. Interesting idea. Except that I am not aware of any disassembler that can correctly generate compiling C# code for lambdas and other anonymous classes..

Comment: You don't need to recompile. have you seen this https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/dotPeek+Symbol+Server+and+PDB+Generation

Comment: Oh, the symbol server thing.. But that mean I have to attach to the running process. I cannot directly attach a debugger. It's a DLL that runs within Unity editor and AFAIK neither MonoDevelop nor VS can attach to the managed part of the editor itself.